# php if statement execution condition

Tags: php

If i have an `if` statement that relies on one of two methods returning false, would both methods run if the first methods returns false. Example:

```
class myClass {
    public function functPublic()
    {
        if(!$this->funct1() || !$this->funct2()){
            print('test');
        }
    }

    private function funct1()
    {
        // complex code here
        return false;
    }

    private function funct2()
    {
        // complex code here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Would the above code execute the `funct2()` method even though it has already recieved a `false` from the `funct1()` method?

Comment: Simplest way to test for yourself is to add a `die("second funct called");` in your function.

Answer (score 3):

If the first condition is evaluated to true, then the second will not be called.
A simple way to test php things like that is to use phpfiddle.org 
Or make a php script yourself, or run it command line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using the methods you suggested, In this case, `funct2()` is never called.

Comment: Yep, basically, in order to optimise code processing, if you have multiple condition, and specifically OR conditions, the interpreter stop checking after the first TRUE found. That way it saves time, cpu, ram etc :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In all these cases, `foo()` is never called.

```
$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

So with

```
function funct1() {
    return false;
}
```

thus

```
if (!$this->funct1() || !$this->funct2())
```

is

```
if (!false || !$this->funct2())
```

is

```
if (true || !$this->funct2())
```

means that `$this->funct2()` is never called.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

No

If first is true then not require to evaluate second.

TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

[Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 0):

using OR, the first check is performed. If that evaluates to true, the second one is not run. Only if the first one evaluates as false would the second one be called.
If you need both to run, use AND instead.